# How do i send an embed in discord.py Example on the Internet just not workin

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send embed in my discord server using python discord.py library but all i get is empty message like this

[image].

Code I used is here:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())


# when the bot is ready to execute commands
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот готов к работе")
    print("------------------")


# member join and member leave
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Добро пожаловать ")


# join voice and leave voice
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:  # if author in voice
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel  # get channel
        await channel.connect()  # connect
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:  # if author in voice
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()  # DC
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")


# kick, ban and unban
@client.command()  # if command kick
# @has_permissions(kick_members=True)  # if user has permission to kick
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Пользователя {member} выгнали")


@kick.error  # if kick command gives and error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("У вас нет прав чтобы выгнать пользователя")


@client.command()  # if command ban
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)  # if user has permissions
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Пользователь {member} был забанен")


@ban.error  # catching error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("У вас нет прав чтобы забанить пользователя")


# embed message
@client.command()
async def ben(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='TEST', description="test", colour=discord.Colour.gold())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

`ctx.send()` just sends empty message and I was browsing for the solution to this problem for 4 hours and still didn't get anything

I tried using `ctx.channel.send()` instead of `ctx.send()` expecting to see correct output but it's still empty. Also I tried to change arguments of Embed function but it has the same result

Comment: The code is correct. The problem is in your bot's permissions or else in your Discord application.
Confirm that your bot has the `Embed Links` permission on the channel.

Answer (score 1):

The Embed looks correct. However, check if the following applies:

1. Your bot has the `Embed Links` permission:

[image]

*You can find this in the role settings of your server*

and

2. You have enabled the following in your settings:

[image]

*You can find this under `Text & Images` in your Discord settings*